# How to query 4 tables in sqlite3 in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Here are my tables. I get 0 rows return.

```
CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
```

Here my SQL code:

```
SELECT Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name 
FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist 
ON Track.genre_id = Genre.id and Track.album_id = Album.id 
WHERE Album.artist_id = Artist.id
ORDER BY Artist.name LIMIT 3
```

I appreciate your looking into this problem.

Comment: When I execute those statements, I have four empty tables. How could there be more than zero rows?

Answer (score 1):

You code is correct sofar, but you need to fill the just created tables with records.

For example by running (untested):

```
INSERT INTO Artist (name) VALUES ('Artist 1'), ('Artist 2');
INSERT INTO Genre (name) VALUES ('Genre 1'), ('Genre 2');

INSERT INTO Album (title, artist_id) VALUES ('Title 1', 1);

INSERT INTO Track(title, album_id, 
    genre_id, len, rating, count) 
    VALUES ('Track 1', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Also you should declare `artist_id`, `album_id` and `genre_id` columns as [foreign keys](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).